# angularjs only in a particular wordpress post

Tags: angularjs, wordpress

I build a website with many pages (event, blog, game....). One page display games (posts). User click on a new game button and there is a new post created.
User click on buttons to play, post is updated and reloaded.

I understand we can set wordpress to be a single application page with `angularjs`.

Is it possible to keep all the website as it is and use `angularjs` only for the game page, post ?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, Just bootstrap ng-app to a wrapper of the section that has to be angularized or add ng-app to that wrapper. That way all the rest stays exactly the same.

Comment: OK, I try and let you know